# Preprocessor macro taking NSString stringWithFormat fails due to comma

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

Assuming I have a macro like this

```
#define A(x) NSLog(@"%@", x)
```

how can I call it and format the string in the macro argument like this

```
A([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Random string with number %d", 5]);
```

I am getting error `too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation` and the error marker points to the comma, which makes sense, since I  assume that is there the preprocessor splits the arguments, since it does not know the context that it is a selector call. Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As the linked question's answer says, the solution lies in using an extra pair of paranthese at the call site:

```
A(([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Random string with number %d", 5]));
```

works.

Comment: yep, that is why already marked this as a duplicate, but wanted to leave it here in case anyone stumbles upon this.